# Prove properties of the alternating multilinear map

Tags: multilinear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ (with $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$) and let $F:L^n(V,K)\to L^n(V,K)$ be a  map defined by
>   $$F(g)(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) := \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)g(x_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc, x_{\sigma(n)}).$$
>   Prove the following:
>   (a) $F$ is a linear map.
>   (b) $F(g) = g$ for every $g\in A^n(V,K)$
>   (c) $\operatorname{im} F = A^n(V,K)$.
>   (d) $F\circ F = F$.
>
> $A^n(V,K)\subseteq L^n(V,K)$ is the vector space of alternating multilinear maps.

Hi guys,

is anyone able to help me with the problem attached?

I think I managed to solve (a) but I don't really have a clue about (b), (c) and (d).

Thanks for your help in advance.
Ralf

Comment: By the definition, I understand (hopefully...) that $\;L(V,K)\;$ is the space of linear functionals on $\;V\;$ , what I would more easily recognize as $\;V^*\;$ , but I really cannot understand what is $\;A^n(V,K)\;$ ...though it must be, I suppose, some kind of subset, or subspace, of $\;L(V,K)\;$ ...

Comment: L(V,K) is supposed to be L^n(V,K), the space of multilinear functions. Sorry, I kind of had to translate the whole thing and forgot to edit that.
A^n(V,K) is the space of alternating multilinear maps, a subspace of L^n(V,K).

Comment: Please type out images. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- if $g$ is a multilinear alternating map, then $g(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)g(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.  Since $\text{sgn}(\sigma)^2 = 1$ for all $\sigma$ and there are $n!$ permutations $\sigma$, substituting this into the definition of $F$ will take care of b)
- b) shows that $A^n(V, K) \subset \text{im}F$, since every multilinear alternating map is mapped by $F$ to itself.  Can you show the other direction?
- d) follows immediately from b) and c): since $F$ maps anything to a multilinear alternating map, and $F$ fixes any multilinear alternating map, $F$ is idempotent.